# How to create a selectable list in Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

I want to create a select that looks like a collection in Materialize CSS.
I know that in order to do something like that on plain HTML I need to use the `size` attribute.

```html
<select id="someSelect" size="8">
    <option value="3">Blabla</option>
    <option value="4">Bla</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Howhever, when I add it, it doesn't change anything, and the `select` is still a dropdown and not a list.

How could I create a selectable list (only one selection at a time) in Materialize CSS?

**EDIT:**
[bahman parsamanesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996904/bahman-parsamanesh) mentioned in his comment the usage of `<div class="collection">` and `<a>` inside it, which is exactly I was looking for, but how could I handle it's onChange?

Comment: I think one way is using `<div class="collection">` and `<a>` inside it.

Comment: @bahman parsamanesh
I've tried it, and this is exactly what I'm looking for, but how could I handle the onChange using it?

Comment: To hanle onChange, you can use onClick for each `<a>`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Oh, I haven't tried this, thank you very much!